# How to disable automatic resolution of shortcuts (.lnk files) in Windows 10? Group policies not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, group-policy

When a target source file/path is changed, any shortcuts (.lnk files) pointed back to them should no longer work. This helps alert me that something is wrong.

**This is what I want to see when running a broken shortcut.lnk**

[image: Problem with Shortcut, do you want to delete this shortcut?]

In all versions of Windows prior to Win10, the following group policies correctly disabled Automatic Resolution of Broken Shortcuts. These no longer work in Windows 10 (21H2).

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoResolveSearch"=dword:00000001
"NoResolveTrack"=dword:00000001
"LinkResolveIgnoreLinkInfo"=dword:00000001

; Group Policy equivalent
;Administartive Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Do not use the search-based method when resolving shell shortcuts = [ENABLED]
;Administartive Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Do not use the tracking-based method when resolving shell shortcuts = [ENABLED]
;Administartive Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer > Do not track Shell shortcuts during roaming = [ENABLED]
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

- Disabling the service Distributed Link Tracking Client (TrkWks) does not prevent Windows 10 21H2 from repairing shortcuts
- [This SuperUser QA](https://superuser.com/q/1231074/11369) suggests using my exact method above, so it seems something has changed with Win10. The only Win10 version I have tested is 21H2.
- If you've tested other versions of Win10, please add a comment and I'll add to this question for reference. Can confirm the above group policies work as intended on Win8.1.

Comment: What dialog *do* you get when clicking on an invalid shortcut? Windows 10 21H2 - I get this dialog that you want, and I don't have any of your registry items. To be in the same situation as me, delete all of them and reboot.

Comment: No dialog, the file just opens. (1) Create `New Text Document.txt` anywhere. (2) Right-click it > Create shortcut or Send to Desktop. (3) Move target file anywhere. (4) Run shortcut. It should fail with dialog shown in my question, but it doesn't fail. It succeeds at opening the file.

Comment: You're right, the known methods for disabling this behavior don't work any more. Seems like Explorer is now ignoring these registry items/policies. It might be worthwhile to file a bug report on the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Did you try any Win10 versions besides 21H2? I don't have a Microsoft account to file bug reports.

Comment: Just tried and it works the same way on 20H2, so this is not new in Windows 10. The Feedback Hub doesn't need a Microsoft account.

Comment: My own opinion is that it's impossible to avoid this feature. These registry updates are obsolete, and have been so for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests, these registry items, and the group policies they
represent, simply have no effect.

I have tested on Windows 10 21H2 and also 20H2 and the results are
the same - Explorer is now just ignoring these registry items and
policies, and apparently has been doing so for some time now.
This advice for doing these registry modifications is now obsolete.

There is not much that you can do, except to file a bug report to
Microsoft on the Feedback Hub. Microsoft is the only one that
can return the situation to what it was before.

Comment: Seems like this is the right answer, so I'm awarding the rep bonus early. Thanks for your effort. Wish it didn't cost me 50 rep.

Comment: @Jeff: I gave back 10 rep.